# Google Contacts API user info URL

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-contacts-api

I am implementing adapter for accessing Google Contacts.
I am looking for the user info URL.

1. API:  Google.GData.Contacts Version 2.2.0
2. Scope: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
3. User info url:  **????????????**

For example in Google Mail using:

1. API:  Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 Version 1.32.2.1132
2. Scope: https://mail.google.com/
3. **3. User info url: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile&access_token=**

By "User info url" I mean the url which returns information about the logged user. In the Google Mail case they return: 
 { "emailAddress": "adapteruser1@hyne.com", "messagesTotal": 3, "threadsTotal": 3, "historyId": "13660" }

Best regards,
 Svet

Comment: What do you mean by "User info url"? Are you referring to the url that [sends an authorized `Get` request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)?

Comment: By "User info url" I mean the url which returns information about the logged  user. In the Google Mail case they return <br/> {
 "emailAddress": "adapteruser1@hydrogen-online.com",
 "messagesTotal": 3,
 "threadsTotal": 3,
 "historyId": "13660"
}